# dylib is not able to load, refreneced from other dylibs

Tags: xcode, macos, dylib, dynamic-library, dyld

I am getting following error when i try to execute my executable:

**Dyld Error Message:

Library not loaded: /Library/Application support/XYZ/a.dylib

Referenced from :/Library/Application support/ABC/b.dylib

Reason: image not found**

I have used "install name tool" in Run script of my Xcode project to change search location for both a.dylib and b.dylib. I have copied the both libraries(a.dylib and b.dylib)from folder XYZ to folder ABC.
(For not linking from old location I have renamed the old folder as _XYZ)

Then also I get above error.

So, Is it any way to change the install name of dylibs which is refrenced from other dylib?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you just upgraded to Yosemite? Had the same issue, this solved it for me:

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/27106#issuecomment-36694023

Comment: No, I have not upgraded anything. There is nothing useful in the link which you have shared.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by changing install name like this

install_name_tool -change "old path" "new path" "path of depended dylib"

ex:

install_name_tool -change "/Library/Application support/XYZ/a.dylib" "/Library/Application support/ABC/a.dylib" "/Library/Application support/ABC/b.dylib"